# What is the difference between $object->$attribute and $object->attribute?

Tags: php, loops, oop, foreach, attributes

There is a `foreach` loop that iterates attributes. If an object has the next attribute, the code assigns a value for this attribute:

```
foreach ($record as $attribute=>$value) {
    if ($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
        $object->$attribute = $value;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why we have to use `$object->$attribute` instead of `$object->attribute`?  The latter seems more logical to me because it looks like basic OOP, but in this case the script doesn't work.

I just want to know why. Please give me some insights.

Comment: He asks for `$object->$attribute = $value;` not `$record as $attribute=>$value` I think

Comment: Karol is right, I ask for " $object->$attribute " ... thanks guys for those links .... i am still learning

Comment: Either way, the links in there explain both scenarios; most particularly this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-do-various-symbols-mean-in-php IMHO and should read more on OOP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Say we declare this: `$property = 'user';`, we can then use this to call the `$user = 'Bob';` variable like so : `echo $$property;` its the same principle. ( outputs bob )

Comment: thanks for all the comments, I got my answer, much appreciated guys <3 <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's a dynamical attribution :

```
$attribute = 'toto'; 
$object->$attribute = 'tata';
echo $object->toto; // will display 'tata'
```

Comment: thanks man ! this explains it straight to the point! :)

Comment: @EldinPHP you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> Class properties may also be accessed using variable property names.
>   The variable property name will be resolved within the scope from
>   which the call is made. For instance, if you have an expression such
>   as `$foo->$bar`, then the local scope will be examined for `$bar` and its
>   value will be used as the name of the property of `$foo`. This is also
>   true if `$bar` is an array access.

Comment: Which this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-do-various-symbols-mean-in-php outlines *"Variable Variables"* where IMHO, the question's a dupe, given the answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes, with some effort I have found _What does the PHP syntax $var1->$var2 mean?_ entry in the list (not in the `$$ Variable Variables` section, by the way)